# Issue in custom flutter search widget's search results selection - flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I build a simple search widget for flutter web. Everything working fine but after I got the search results, I have to click twice on the result to select a specific search result. Please help me to figure out the problem. I tried for several day but no luck. I'm using flutter 2.5.2 version.

[darpad link](https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?id=bd4b3f7e6c8c08c1b9ec30c42e2b9a4e) to run the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: SearchView(),
  ));
}

class SearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SearchView> createState() => _SearchViewState();
}

class _SearchViewState extends State<SearchView> {
  String searchResult = '';
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> data = ['Result 1', 'Result 2', 'Result 3', 'Result 4'];

  Future<List<String>> loadData() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (this.textController.text.trim().length != 0) {
        return data;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.textController.addListener(this._onTextChanged);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onTextChanged() {
    print('text cahnged');
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Brand'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: this.textController,
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: loadData(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.hasData) {
                  print("future build");
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      for (String result in snapshot.data)
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('Clicked');
                            setState(() {
                              this.textController.clear();
                              this.searchResult = result;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text(result),
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
            Text('Search result is ${searchResult}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This weird behavior happens because of a flutter [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79982). Before flutter version 2.5, Text change listeners only listen for text changes. But from version 2.5, listeners also listen for focus change events. Need to use `onChanged` method in `TextFormField` until flutter fix the issue.